# How to build a UI of two textfields in a 'panel' on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, toolbar, uitoolbar

I want to build a UI with textfields.

I need two textfields appear in a "panel" and I have control of that "panel" to have it display or not display. How can I make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the two text fields to a view, then implement the current view controller to present a [modal view controller](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController:animated:) on some event (perhaps a button click)

Comment: Can I make it by the Interface Builder?